# Swift 3 FileManagerDelegate: shouldRemoveItemAt compiler error

Tags: swift3, xcode8

While using Xcode 8 and Swift 3, I am trying to implement the following method for the FileManagerDelegate protocol:

```
  private func fileManager(_ fileManager: FileManager, shouldRemoveItemAt URL: URL) -> Bool {
    var shouldDelete = true
    let urlString = URL.absoluteString
    if urlString?.range(of: "keepfiles") != nil {
      shouldDelete =  false
    }
    return shouldDelete
  }
```

the compiler shows the following error:

```
Use of undeclared type: 'URL'
```

but it does not offer any solution to fix it. Because of this I cannot test the selective deletion. If I change the URL type declaration to NSURL, the error goes away, but the delegate never gets called and all the files get deleted.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were trying to get the `absoluteString` from the `type` `URL` instead of  instance `url`. Change your parameter name into a more readable format and do like this, the error will go away.

```
private func fileManager(_ fileManager: FileManager, shouldRemoveItemAt url: URL) -> Bool {
            var shouldDelete = true
            let urlString = url.absoluteString
            if urlString?.range(of: "keepfiles") != nil {
                shouldDelete =  false
            }
            return shouldDelete
        }
```

Comment: The odd thing is that the URL: URL part  was generated by Xcode autocompletion; perhaps I should report this in the.bug reporter?

Comment: @MichaelSheaver  May be, If you think so, Double check it anyways.